# Prevent blender from changing import rotations

Tags: animation, 3d, blender

I have a .bvh file that I am importing into blender and while the imported model looks correct, the rotations on the relevant joints are different, that is, the rotation values blender is using is not the same ones in the file. I can't find the equivalent rotation files inside the .bvh file which stores all rotations values.

Is there a way I can stop blender from altering the rotations and stick strictly to using the rotations inside the BVH file?